# Notice: Undefined index: users.username PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I get

```
Notice: Undefined index: replies.reply_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\proiect\topic.php on line 25
```

error and I do not know why. Here is my code.
I get it also for users.username and for replies.reply_content.
Here is the sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT replies.reply_topic, replies.reply_content, replies.reply_date, replies.reply_by, users.user_id, users.username
                FROM replies LEFT JOIN users ON replies.reply_by = users.user_id
                WHERE replies.reply_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

And here is the while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        echo $row['users.username'].'</br>'.$row['replies.reply_date'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        echo $row['replies.reply_content'];
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
```

Comment: `var_dump` `$row` and see what it _actually_ contains.

Comment: It is a notice not an error but you should not need the table name just do `$row['username']` etc